# How to add radiobutton with dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I'm scripting HTML with dynamic form and have a some problem with radio button.

I was tried to change "name='some[]'" to "name='some'" and change the 'id' different with other.

In View:

```
$nam = $this - > input - > post("name", TRUE);
$jek = $this - > input - > post("sex", TRUE);
$hub = $this - > input - > post("hub", TRUE);
for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($nam); $x++) {
  $array[] = array('name' => $nam[$x], 'sex' => $jek[$x], 'hub' => $hub[$x]);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sex</label>
  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="sex[]" value="0"> Female
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="sex[]" value="1"> Male
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kinship</label>
  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
      <input type="radio" name="hub[]"> Wife
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="hub[]"> Daughter/Son
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="hub[]"> Other
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [sex] => 1 [hub] => on) [1] => Array ( [sex] => [hub] => ) )
```

when i selected:

1. sex=0, hub=wife
2. sex=1, hub=daughter/son

Comment: console say that there's an unexpected token '>' .. otherwise your code seems to run.. what exactly  are you trying to do? Question is vague

Comment: I'm trying to using radiobutton on dynamic form and i got a failed.